# Resetting a height value to it's initial null (or auto?) after assigning a value

Tags: jquery, css

I have a div (`.projectContainer`) which dynamically resizes with the window, and maintains it's aspect ratio as explained [here](http://www.mademyday.de/css-height-equals-width-with-pure-css.html), using pseudo elements (`.projectContainer:after`). This works because there is no assigned height value.

However, if the div is clicked, I want it to move to a certain spot and become a certain height and width. At this point, I  assign a height value. However, if the div is clicked again, I want it to return to it's initial spot, width and height. But by removing the height value from the div or assigning it to null, rather than take on the padding from the pseudo div, it instead shrinks down to 0 height.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/4bd5jv8y/) is a fiddle demonstrating.

How can I get it to once again inherit the values from `.projectContainer:after`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `initial` for the height property instead ;)

Comment: When you set the css of a specific element, you can get it to take on its original stylesheet properties by resetting the specific style properties to `initial` for that element.

Comment: Uggh, I swear that was an option I tried. Thanks a lot!